# Residue of highly oscillating function

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to compute the contour integral

$ \int  z^{2n-1} \exp\left(- i k \log \left(\frac{1-z}{1+z} \right) \right) dz $

over the unit circle in $\mathbb C$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $k \in \mathbb R$, where $i^2 = -1$. The contribution from the pole at $z=0$ is clear. The problem is that the function is not really well defined at $z = \pm 1$ and I would like to avoid those points with a contour deformation (which I can justify in the context of the problem). If the residue at $z = \pm 1$ would be zero by some argument, I wouldn't matter how I avoid those points, showing that the result is unique.

Does anyone know how to argue this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No residue can be defined at branch points. Instead, we might be able to prove the integral around a branch point vanishes.

Comment: I see, thanks. In fact, the integral converges to zero around z = \pm 1 as the integrand is bounded.